# Structure of MongoDB vs MySQL

Tags: mysql, mongodb, nosql

As mentioned in the following article  : http://www.couchbase.com/why-nosql/nosql-database

`When looking up data, the desired information needs to be collected from many tables (often hundreds in today’s enterprise applications) and combined before it can be provided to the application. Similarly, when writing data, the write needs to be coordinated and performed on many tables.`

and the given example of data in JSON format tells

`ease of efficiently distributing the resulting documents and read and write performance improvements make it an easy trade-off for web-based applications`

But what if i capture all my data in a single table in mysql as is done in mongoDB [in the link given] , would that performance be like equivalent to mongoDB [meaning extracting data from mysql without JOINS] ?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the structure you require. The main point of splitting data into tables is being able to index pieces of data, accelerating the retrieval of data.

Another point is that the normalization that a relational database offers ties you to a rigid structure. You can, of course, store json in mysql, but the json document won't have its pieces indexed. If you want fast retrieval of a json document by its pieces then you are looking into splitting it into parts.

If your data can change, which means, doesn't require a schema, then use Mongo.

If your data structure doesn't change then I'd go with MySQL